# Dynamic Passing Function as Argument

Tags: functions

```
Dynamic[\[Theta]SFG[\[Lambda]2a_, \[Theta]2_, \[Lambda]3a_, \
\[Theta]3_] := 
  ArcSin[(Sin[\[Theta]2/57.29577]/\[Lambda]2a + 
     Sin[\[Theta]3/57.29577]/\[Lambda]3a)/(
    1/\[Lambda]2a + 1/\[Lambda]3a)]*57.29577]

Dynamic[\[Theta]refr1[\[Theta]SFG_, ni_, n1_] := 
  ArcSin[(ni Sin[\[Theta]SFG/57.29577])/n1]*57.29577]

Dynamic[\[Theta]refr1[\[Theta]SFG, ni, n1]]
```

Help! I have managed to get the dynamic value of SFG, but for refr1 it stills displays the formula instead of the value! Is there anything wrong with my code?Btw [Lambda]2a and [Lambda]3a are functions too but I still managed to get the value of SFG. Used the same method for refr1 but not sure why it couldn't work

Comment: Btw \[Lambda]2a and \[Lambda]3a are functions too!